# Google chrome green outline around red images in white background

Tags: updates, graphics, google-chrome, intel-graphics

I'm facing an issue which I have attached in the image below.

On the left is a screenshot taken on my laptop screen and on the right is a screenshot taken on the external monitor. I'm getting this issue after a software update. (using `sudo apt-get upgrade`), the same issue is there for another colleague who's using a laptop of the same model.

While my laptop is running Ubuntu 16.04, the other laptop is running Ubuntu 18.04.

Following, are the details of the laptop:

- Model: Asus Vivobook X542UAR.
- Graphics: Intel UHD Graphics 620.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it's something to do with how GPU handles the chrome graphics.
Issue resolved after turning off Hardware acceleration on chrome settings.

Go to `chrome://settings` and disable `Use hardware acceleration when available`

Answer (score 10):

It is a known bug in chrome that occurs on images with partial transparency when the host OS met some specific conditions:

- Host use Software rasterization (so Linux, or a blacklisted GPU)
- Host use a color profile that doesn't fully enclose sRGB. Most profiles are sRGB,
  and most non-sRGB profiles are strictly larger than sRGB.

Potential work-around:

- Go to `chrome://flags#force-color-profile`, and set it to `sRGB`.

OR

- Go to `chrome://settings/?search=Use%20hardware%20acceleration%20when%20available`, and and disable `Use hardware acceleration when available`.

This bug will be fixed on chromium 70.

[Link to chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=867813&q=hardware-acceleration%20green&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)